# Simulate database I/O behaviour

Tags: linux, hard-drive, io

I'm investigating some performance issue and I need a tool that can mock the same I/O behavior that a typical RDBMS is usually creating.
I don't want to install a full blown RDBMS and mess around with configuration just in order to test this issue.

Is there any tool designaed for this specific need ?

Comment: you can use oracle orion, but i think you need a database installed

Comment: Completely irrelevant to your question, `sqlio` for Windows does this. The Answer below handles Linux nicely.

Comment: Can't see how this question is seeking product,service or material recoomendation. It's seeking for a method to simulate a situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you know your database block size, number of threads, and percentage of read vs write, [iozone](http://www.iozone.org/) can be used to craft IO workloads which might mimic production.

[Filebench](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/filebench/index.php?title=Main_Page) ships with a large number of "personalities" which can mimic an application workload, including a database application, and even has its own markup language to enable you to write your own workload personality.

Answer (score 0):

There's also the blktrace ([btrecord](http://linux.die.net/man/8/btrecord)) approach on Linux. You can capture real I/O activity and replay ([btreplay](http://linux.die.net/man/8/btreplay)) onto the same device or different device. The [fio](http://freecode.com/projects/fio) tool also supports this.